# Multiple Authors with common affiliations in IEEEtran conference template simple author name

Tags: titles, ieeetran, affiliation

I have a paper where I have 4 different authors with a common affiliation. I would like to mention their names and then a single affiliation followed by individual mail addresses. I have included the code I have . I am using TexStudio and am new to LaTeX. Please help me and tell me the correct use of \author for this.
I don't want each author to be marked with an upper index.(just a simple name)

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\begin{document}
\title{An Important Conference Contribution}

\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{Author One\IEEEauthorrefmark{1},
Author Two\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}, Author Three\IEEEauthorrefmark{3} and
Author Four\IEEEauthorrefmark{4}}
\IEEEauthorblockA{Department of Whatever,
Whichever University\\
Wherever\\
Email: \IEEEauthorrefmark{1}author.one@add.on.net,
\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}author.two@add.on.net,
\IEEEauthorrefmark{3}author.three@add.on.net,
\IEEEauthorrefmark{4}author.four@add.on.net}}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can delete `\IEEEauthorrefmark{X}`. This is what create the upper symbol/index:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\begin{document}
\title{An Important Conference Contribution}

\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{Author One,
Author Two, Author Three and
Author Four}
\IEEEauthorblockA{Department of Whatever,
Whichever University\\
Wherever\\
Email: author.one@add.on.net,
author.two@add.on.net,
author.three@add.on.net,
author.four@add.on.net}}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: thanks, is this still acceptable by IEEE ? i mean if i separate the authors by comma.

Comment: @JohnSmith I don't know, I'm not member of IEEE board or some but I think so

Comment: @JohnSmith Using a semicolon to separate the email addresses seems to be more common.